# Public access after attaching security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am facing the situation that my RDS instances (PostgreSQL) cannot be connected outside of VPC even after I added security group that open port 5432 for all IPs and configured Yes to Public access section.

RDS Info:
[image: RDS info]

Security Group:
[image: Security group info]

Does anyone face the same situation?
Any solution to fix this?

I'm assuming there is some delay in configuring the Public access section or security group.

Comment: Did you set it up in public subnets?

Comment: how did you try connecting the RDS ? is it from ec2 or any client?
if you haven't tried with ec2 - please try once with connecting rds with ec2 and see if it is accessible.

Comment: I configured RDS to be behind a VPC and it works from EC2 in the same VPC. However, it's not accessible from outside.

Comment: This would tend to suggest either a NACL or routing issue on your VPC. As others have said, a public-style subnet would need to have routes from internet -> VPC /and/ from VPC -> Internet, and would likely solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you can connect with an EC2 instance and everything else appears set up correctly you need to verify your subnet group is using public subnets if you'd like to expose your database publicly. You can check your subnet group and subnets on the instance details for your RDS instance. Under Security and Network you should find something like:

**Subnet group**

```
examplegroup
```

**Subnets**

```
subnet-84b243ef
subnet-etu1769c
subnet-186b3f30
```

You then need to review those subnets and find out how they are configured:

- Go to the VPC dashboard
- Click subnets
- Pick the subnet you want to check
- Click route table
- If its public you should see something like this:

#### Example route table:

```
Destination | Target

10.0.0.0/16 | local

0.0.0.0/0   | igw-e2f87847
```

An `igw` indicates an internet gateway. If you see something like `nat` instead for the `0.0.0.0/0` entry it likely means this is a private subnet.

You can do this programatically in `bash` using the `aws cli` and `jq`. This will list all route tables associated with the given db instance's subnet group subnets:

```
instance_name='example'
aws rds describe-db-instances --filter Name=db-instance-id,Values=${instance_name} | jq .DBInstances[].DBSubnetGroup.Subnets[].SubnetIdentifier -r | while read subnet; do
  aws ec2 describe-route-tables --filters Name=association.subnet-id,Values=${subnet} | jq .RouteTables[].Routes
done
```

Comment: Thanks, Brandon. I checked and found that the RDS instance is using 6 subnets in which 3 are public and 3 are private. What can be the problem here?

Comment: I just found out that might be the RDS instance was attached to private subnet instead of a public one. Any idea to avoid this?

Comment: Make sure your subnet group is set up for what you want, which in this case is public. Either make a new subnet group or remove the private subnets from the existing one. The instance will attach to a random one in that group.

Comment: Okay. I got it. As it's randomly attached to a subnet, so it should always be public/ private depending on the purposes. I also created few RDS subnet groups to separate these. Thanks for your answer.